# ending method if editText empty

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-source

This is a tip calculator app in Java. If both fields are not filled in, it should show an error message in a `TextView`, but it just freezes the app... any tips?

```
package tip.calculator;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;




public class TipCalculator extends Activity 
{

private Button enter;
EditText myEditField ;
EditText myEditField2;
float percentage = 0;
float percentageInp = 0;
float billAmount = 0;
double output = 0; 
String output1 = "";
Button clearButton ;
TextView textView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myEditField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentText);
    enter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    myEditField2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billText);
    clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearButton);


    enter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {

             TextView errors;
             textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             errors = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorText);    




             if(myEditField.getText().equals("")){
                 errors.setText("Percent must be filled in");


             }

             if(myEditField.getText().equals("")){
                 errors.setText("Bill Amount must be filled in");

             }




            percentageInp = Float.parseFloat(myEditField.getText().toString());
            billAmount = Float.parseFloat(myEditField2.getText().toString());

            percentage = ((float)percentageInp /100);

            output = (double)(billAmount * percentage);

            double result = output * 100;
            result = Math.round(result);
            result = result / 100;

            output1 = Double.toString(result);

            textView.setText(output1 + " $");

        }
    });

    clearButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            percentage = 0;
            output = 0;
            output1 = "";

            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.errorText);
            textView.setText("");

            TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentText);
            textView2.setText("");

            TextView textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.billText);
            textView3.setText("");


            TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView1.setText("");


            percentageInp = 0;
            billAmount = 0;

            myEditField.clearComposingText();
            myEditField2.clearComposingText();



            return;
        }


    });
}*
```

}

here is the layout xml(provided by request)...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/errorText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="onEnterClick" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/billText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Bill Amount"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|textAutoComplete"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/percentText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/billText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/billText"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Percent"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:singleLine="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/percentText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Calculate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/percentText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/billText"
        android:text="$"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/percentText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="%"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clearButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Clear" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/clearButton"
        android:text="Solution Will Appear Here"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/errorText"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the LogCat output (errors only)

```
08-01 20:49:08.424: E/(13643): URE: SkPaint in getMeasureCacheProc index: 2
08-01 20:49:08.689: E/(13643): URE: SkPaint in getMeasureCacheProc index: 2
08-01 20:49:10.844: E/(13643): URE: SkPaint in getMeasureCacheProc index: 2
08-01 20:49:12.074: E/(13643): URE: SkPaint in getMeasureCacheProc index: 2
08-01 20:49:12.254: E/(13643): URE: SkPaint in getMeasureCacheProc index: 2
08-01 20:49:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(13643): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 20:49:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(13643): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
08-01 20:49:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(13643):    at tip.calculator.TipCalculator$2.onClick(TipCalculator.java:91)
08-01 20:49:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(13643):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3620)
08-01 20:49:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(13643):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14292)
08-01 20:49:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(13643):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-01 20:49:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(13643):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-01 20:49:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(13643):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 20:49:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(13643):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
08-01 20:49:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(13643):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 20:49:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(13643):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 20:49:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(13643):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
08-01 20:49:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(13643):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
08-01 20:49:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(13643):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What does parseFloat() return on an empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your LogCat, I get it there is no `TextView` with the id *errorText*, but you don't see any errors at compiling time, as you have a `RelativeLayout` with this id; but you get the `ClassCastException` error at runtime.

```
 errors = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorText);
```

Also, always use `""..equals(myEditField.getText())` instead `myEditField.getText().equals("")` (that is, the hardcoded value first).

Otherwise, if your `EditText` is empty, `myEditField.getText()` will return *null*, so you'll have an error trying to use the equals() method on *null*.

Alternatively, you can use `myEditField.getText().length() = 0` to check if the `EditText` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `return` in `onClick`? Also you have an `*` in the second to last `}` I don't know if that solves your problems but it was something that caught my attention.